# Nautilus disables mouse and keyboard when copying files

Tags: keyboard, nautilus, mouse, 22.10

Since I updated ubuntu to the latest version with "Nautilus 43.0", when copying or moving files, if I keep the popup indicating the progress of the operation open, the keyboard and mouse keys stop working until until I close the nautilus popup.

[image]

For example, the screenshot of this question with the popup, I had to take it from another question because while copying some files the "StampRsist" key to take a picture of my screen didn't work either.

Does this happen to you too? what is this due to? how can i fix this?

**Update:** The bug seems to go away if I activate wayland. but with wayland active I can't use XRANDR to configure the pc screens at startup.

Comment: This bug is not only in Nautilus, but in Gnome 43 (Xorg) in general.

Comment: I can verify that this is also the case to a degree with Wayland as well. The copy dialogue pop-out in Nautilus blocks any other type of desktop interaction with the mouse. You have to click somewhere else in order for the Nautilus copy pop-out to disappear before you can do anything else. This is happening on both my Ubuntu 22.10 systems; one running Xorg and the other running Wayland. It's a VERY annoying bug...